# git authentication using ssh keys via gpg-agent under ubuntu 16.10 not working

Tags: ssh, git, gnupg

I just installed ubuntu 16.10.

I have gpg-agent doing my ssh authentication. It works well and I can ssh without any problems with it.

but when I use git, git does not contact the ssh-agent (gpg-agent, really). it works under 16.04, but not 16.10

```
printenv | grep SSH                         
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
```

```
git pull
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/dmg/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dmg/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/dmg/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dmg/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/dmg/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

as I have already mentioned, ssh authentication works when running ssh directly, but not when running git.

thank you for any hints/help.

Comment: `ssh-add -l` do you have the keys added to your agent? All the tried keys are rejected by the server. Is it configured properly? What is the key that should authenticate you?